# java program that has three buttons, each displaying a different text that when pressed will display the text on the button in a text box

Tags: java

I have an assignment to write a program that has three buttons, each displaying a different text that when pressed will display the text on the button in a text box. I think I have the basics of the program down but I can't get it to run. I've tried watching tutorials and reading up on the error I've been getting but I can't seem to figure it out. I am new to programming in java and have been pretty confused throughout the whole course. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

right now my errors are:
non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
objButton1.addActionListener(this);

non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
objButton2.addActionListener(this);

non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
objButton3.addActionListener(this);

cannot find symbol
if (e.getSource()==objButton1)

cannot find symbol
else if (e.getSource()==objButton2)

```
import java.applet.Applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Option3 extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
    Option3()
    {
        setTitle("Option 3");
        setSize (300,300);
        show();
    }
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Frame objFrame;
        Button objButton1;
        Button objButton2;
        Button objButton3;
        TextField objTextField;

        objFrame = new Option3();
        objButton1 = new Button("A");
        objButton2 = new Button("B");
        objButton3 = new Button("C");
        objTextField = new TextField(100);

        objButton1.addActionListener(this);
        objButton2.addActionListener(this);
        objButton3.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource() == objButton1 )

            System.out.println("A");
        else if (e.getSource() == objButton2 )
            System.out.println("B");
        else
            System.out.println("C");    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to change in order to make this work.

1) If you want to access the buttons in the `actionPerformed(...)` method, you need to increase their scope. As it is now, those variables can be accessed only in the `main(...)` method.

2) You need to pass an instance of `ActionListener` to the `addActionListener(...)` method and because `main(...)` is a `static` method, you can't use the `this` keyword, what you can do is to use the `Option3` instance that you've just created or a better solution will be to create those components inside the `Option3` constructor where you can use `this`.

3) If you want to display the components you've created, you need to add them to the frame.

```
import java.applet.Applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Option3 extends Frame implements ActionListener {

    Button objButton1;
    Button objButton2;
    Button objButton3;
    TextField objTextField;

    Option3() {
        setTitle("Option 3");
        setSize (300,300); // is better to control the frame's size by using panels with appropriate layout managers.

        objButton1 = new Button("A");
        objButton2 = new Button("B");
        objButton3 = new Button("C");
        objTextField = new TextField(100);

        objButton1.addActionListener(this);
        objButton2.addActionListener(this);
        objButton3.addActionListener(this);

        Panel panel = new Panel(); // set a layout to this panel based on how you want the components to be displayed.
        panel.add(objButton1);
        panel.add(objButton2);
        panel.add(objButton3);
        panel.add(objTextField);

        add(panel);

        show();
    }
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Frame objFrame = new Option3();

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == objButton1 ) { //delimit this kind of statements using curly braces to avoid confusion and bugs.
            System.out.println("A");
        } else if (e.getSource() == objButton2 ) {
            System.out.println("B");
        } else {
            System.out.println("C");    
        }
    }
}
```